# I want to take snapshot of media stream in Vline

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, vline

Is there a way to take snapshot of the incoming video stream in vline?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [snagit](http://snagit.joydownload.com/?c=61&gclid=CKHYyZHzt70CFdShtAodfgoA1A) and assign a hot key for quick capture screen.
tools->program prefrences->hotkeys
i set it to ctrl+alt+shift+p